# how to remove grub menu after deleting ubuntu if my bootable usb option is not shown in boot menu?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have deleted Ubuntu from windows 8.1
Now every time their is grub menu shown on the boot, and my bootable usb is also not shown in boot menu so that I can repare my windows?
Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter into the BIOS of your PC to select your bootable usb as the 1st boot device.

This is done at startup of the machine, usually by pressing keys like DEL, ESC, F2, F8, F10, F12, ... depending on the machine. The specific key to press is specified in the user manual of your machine (if laptop) or the motherboard (if desktop).

You may also additionally have to set your `boot mode` to `Legacy` in your BIOS options.

Comment: I have done this but it shows EFI usb device boot failed

Comment: @vkrpro Look in your bios for the option called `boot mode` and set it to `legacy` instead of `UEFI`, then choose to boot from your device.

Comment: I actually figured out that my bios have been corrupted due the bugs in ubuntu 17.10. That's why bios is not saving any changes.

Comment: Do you have a way by which i can repair my bios